# Collection of stories about young boy and his brother encountering aliens in suburbia

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, childrens-novel

I'm trying to find a book that one of our teachers read to us in elementary school. It is either a collection of short stories, or simply one of those novels written in episodic form. It's told in first person by a young boy. He and his brother have various intriguing suburban encounters with alien creatures.

One story (or chapter) involves a peculiar child who comes to the boys' birthday party, and gives them a strange ball that no one can ever pick up, no matter how much they chase after it. Another story prominently features an area of the neighborhood called "No-Mom's Land," and also mentions Sno Balls as the boys' favorite snack. Real useful, I know, but if this sounds familiar, please let me know! It's a light, fun read that I remember liking a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I searched for "no-mom's land" on google books and found one called [*My Life Among the Aliens*](https://books.google.com/books?id=dRpHr0DCoZIC&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22no-mom%27s%20land%22) by Gail Gauthier, could this be it? One of the reviews on the [amazon page](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0590340840):

> Will and Robby have been spotting many different kinds of aliens. One
>   alien came to Will's ninth birthday party uninvited, another came to
>   earth acting and pretending like a neighbors dog, Sandy, and one came
>   as Santa Claus. One thing that is stopping them is their parents, not
>   believing what they say about their alien encounters. Their mom tells
>   them not to say the word 'alien' in the house, and their dad thinks
>   they're watching too much TV. In fact, there is another problem too.
>   Some aliens are on Earth to take over it, and some are here just to
>   experience life on another planet. Read this book to find out what
>   happens to Will, Robby, and the aliens.

Comment: Hypnosifl, that's it! Thanks! The cover is even the exact same as the edition our teacher read to us!